# How do I set up a simple all-access shared folder on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I have two Windows 7 Professional computers that I sometimes want to transfer large amounts of files between on my home LAN. I want to designate a folder as shared, and give any unauthenticated user on my LAN full read and write access to everything in it.

Things I have tried:

- Folder Properties / Sharing / Advanced Sharing:

  - Check "Share this Folder"
  - Permissions: Check "Allow" on everything for user "Everyone"
- Network and Sharing Center

  - Joined a common HomeGroup
  - Under "Advanced sharing settings", selected:

    - Turn on network discovery
    - Turn on file and printer sharing
    - Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can read and write files in the Public folders
    - Use 128-bit encryption to help protect file sharing connections
    - Turn off password protected sharing
    - Allow windows to manage homegroup connections
- Unshared and re-shared the folder after all this

Still I am being told I don't have permission to read the share

Answer (score 1):

There is sharing permissions, then there is file and folder permissions. the most restrictive permission will always have priority in Windows.

Right click on the folder and select Properties, then go to the Security tab, add the Everyone  to the list of Group or User names and give it full control.